# Client Script: Field Change

Tags: netsuite

I need to make a field change using a client script.

How can I determine if the form is Create, Copy or Edit?

ex.

```
function fieldChange_test(type, name){

         //insert code to determine if form is edit??
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do nlapiGetRecordId, if it returns null then the record is being created.  If it returns an internal id, the record is being editted.  If a record is copied, then the copy will also have a null internal id.

Comment: how can i determine if it is being created or being copied?

Comment: This concept is sound enough, however nlapiGetRecordId() returns an empty string if it is a create or copy event - not null.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values of the URL parameters in the client script to check this

- if "e=T" is there, it means it is in edit mode.
- if "cp=T" is there, it means it is a copy  of record "id=xx" and "rectype=yy"
- if none of the above two, and just the "rectype=yy" is there, its a Create mode

Answer (score -1):

There is no specific method to determine this using Client Script,
But i believe you can achieve the same result if you try to do it using User Event Script.
Use the before load function and read the execution type.
Example :

```
function userEventBeforeLoad(type, form, request){
  if(type=='create')
      // do create
  elseif(type=='edit')
      // do edit
  elseif(type=='copy')
      // do copy
}
```